# Exception java.io.IOException: Failed to set permissions of path: \tmp\hadoop-user\mapred\staging\user1322875957\.staging to 0700

Tags: java, apache, hadoop, vectorization, mahout

```
14/09/24 14:55:04 ERROR security.UserGroupInformation: PriviledgedActionException as:user cause:java.io.IOException: Failed to set permissions of path: \tmp\hadoop-user\mapred\staging\user1322875957\.staging to 0700
java.io.IOException: Failed to set permissions of path: \tmp\hadoop-user\mapred\staging\user1322875957\.staging to 0700
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.checkReturnValue(FileUtil.java:691)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.setPermission(FileUtil.java:664)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.setPermission(RawLocalFileSystem.java:514)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.mkdirs(RawLocalFileSystem.java:349)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FilterFileSystem.mkdirs(FilterFileSystem.java:193)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmissionFiles.getStagingDir(JobSubmissionFiles.java:126)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:942)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:936)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1190)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJobInternal(JobClient.java:936)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:550)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.waitForCompletion(Job.java:580)
    at org.apache.mahout.vectorizer.DocumentProcessor.tokenizeDocuments(DocumentProcessor.java:93)
    at com.xxx.mahout.Vectorizer.tokenizeDocument(Vectorizer.java:262)
    at com.xxx.mahout.Vectorizer.generateVector(Vectorizer.java:142)
    at com.xxx.others.Dabconnections.getProducts(MongoConnections.java:124)
    at com.xxx.others.MongoConnections.main(MongoConnections.java:180)
```

I got an exception while using mahout.
I can get data from database and generate sequence file using that data.After that when I try to vectorize that sequence file, i am getting this exception.How do i resolve this ? I am using windows 7.

Comment: Hi, Its permission problem. You need to set all Read,Write,Execute permission to input folder. Is your input file on HDFS?

Comment: i am using my local machine  i don't know is that in HDFS?
But i have a server machine which is hadoop configured in HDFS, but i don't know how to run my program in server.

Comment: Which hadoop distribution you using? Is it something like Hortonworks Data platform(HDP2) or Cloudera.

Comment: Hadoop 0.18.0 distribution